# modifying angularFire resolve

Tags: firebase

I would like to modify the angularFire code below (taken from the docs:
https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide.html#section-angular-authentication)
so that if the user is not logged in it will also log the user in before page loads and the user data will be ready to use straight away.

This is the original:

```
resolve: {
  "currentUser": ["simpleLogin", function(simpleLogin) {
    return simpleLogin.$getCurrentUser();
  }]
}
```

and this is what I have so far:

```
resolve: {
  "currentUser": ["simpleLogin", function(simpleLogin) {
    return simpleLogin.$getCurrentUser();
  }],
  "loginUser": ["simpleLogin", function(simpleLogin) {
    return simpleLogin.$login("anonymous", {rememberMe : true} );
  }]
}
```

but this will cause the user to be logged in each time thus resetting the ID (I think?). How do I do it conditionally so that they are only logged in if not already?

Comment: Tony, if you try to log them in automatically, you're going to run into popup blockers and other issues, since this is not run based on a user action.

Comment: What do you recommend I do then? It's an online text editor where they are automatically directed to a unique "pad" a bit like firepad. I need to know who is writing what??? Thanks (it's Tom by the way!) ha ha

Comment: I don't want to use Firepad either!

Comment: Will pop up blockers be an issue for anonymous login @kato

Comment: No, not for anonymous login. I seem to have gotten most everything wrong in my comment :( Sorry about that, Tony-Tommy-Tom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than utilizing two resolve methods, I'd just chain them together. Since $login returns a promise, this is pretty smooth sailing:

```
resolve: {
  "currentUser": ["simpleLogin", function(simpleLogin) {
    return simpleLogin.$getCurrentUser().then(function(user) {
       if( user === null ) {
          // log in now...
          return simpleLogin.$login('anonymous', {rememberMe: true}); 
       }
       else {
          // logged in!
          return user;
       }
    });
  }]
}
```